# Adding Text input to BootStrap 3 Tab

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bs3 tab panel with 3 tabs. The third tab I'm using as a search button. When the user clicks on the tab it displays the textbox for input.

I'm trying to get the textbox aligned to the left side of the tab. What would be the best way to do that.

[image: sample]

Live example at http://jsfiddle.net/xnmktc54/3/

Here is a sample of my html:

```
<div role="tabpanel">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Friends" aria-controls="Friends" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Friends</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#Invite" aria-controls="Invite" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Invite</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="pull-right">
            <input id="xx" type="text" style="display: none; position: absolute;" /><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#xx').toggle('fast'); return false;">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Friends">
            <p>test 1</p>
            <p>test 2</p>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Invite">
            <p>test 3</p>
            <p>test 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put up a live example?

Comment: Forgot to add the link. It's there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inline css and never use any of that again if you can.

```
input#xx{position:absolute};
```

override bootstrap.min.css:5

```
.nav-tabs>li>a {display:inline-block};
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add "right:Amount of Pixels You want" to the css code.  See the code below.

```
<input id="xx" type="text" style="display: none; position: absolute; right:80px;" />
```

Check it out in this jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/xnmktc54/11/